# Is there a simple script to crop an occupancy map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many mapping approaches generate huge maps with a lot of free space around it, which slows down move_base, etc.

Is there already some script that does the cropping automatically including updating the origin correctly?

There already is a [related ticket](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/3) for the map server to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60682/is-there-a-simple-script-to-crop-an-occupancy-map?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone need something like that. Here is one:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/29/files

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0